# URL call fails without phone permission

Tags: android, validation, permissions, certificate

I am doing certificate validation, and it works if I have the read_phone_state permission given.But without that permission I get this

```
<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 13653108843900521969</body></html>
```

It is strange, why do I get successful data when I have phone permission given but when not I get that error.Is the bug server side, or my android code ???